# Test a signal's existance from its name written in a string

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I'm having a problem with modelsim and I'm not even sure that a solution exists.

For one of my projects, I have to drive (and spy) some testbench signals with text files as input. I want to use *init_signal_drive* and *init_signal_spy* procedure to keep signal names (in text files) as string.

The problem is : if the name in the text file doesn't fit the actual name of the signal in the testbench, functions *init_signal_xxx* will fail without lots of information.

What I want to do is to test the existance of the signal from its "string" name before calling the *init_signal_xxx* procedure.

Does anyone know if it's possible and how to do it ?

A second solution for my problem would be to catch the state of the *init_signal_xxx* procedure (passed or failed), but I'm not sure it's possible anyway.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What method do you use to get the actual signal from it's name string?

Comment: Good question! I have made a huge pause on this project and now I'm trying to restart it I'm facing an issue I haven't seen. Signal_force procedure is the good solution to write values from text files to signals. But there is no opposite procedure as reading a signal value and returning it into a "string". I don't know how to do it and it may worth a new topic

Comment: solution Found using FLI : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491317/modelsim-reading-a-signal-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted, you could make a record with strings to 'wrap' around your actual signal. This is a little kludgey, but it is hard for me to think of another way, short of head-hurting magic with files that would be even worse in VHDL. So:

```
type stdWithName is
     record
         name : String;
         value : std_logic;
end record;
```

you could then initialize this like:

```
signal val : std_logic := '0';
signal withName : stdWithName := ("withName",val);
```

and compare the name like

```
if (withName.name = "withName") then
      -- huzzah! a match. 
end if;
```

Comment: Hi heisenBug, I think that I'll have to reference all my signal's names into a record.