# Modelsim / reading a signal value

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

In my simulation, I want to have RW access to signals whereever there are in the project. To get the write access, I use the "signal_force" procedure from the modelsim_lib library. But to get the read access I havn't find the corresponding function.

The reason why signal_force fit my needs is that I'm working with input text files, so I have the name and the value of the signal from a "string" or a "line" variable and I can directly give these variable to the fonction.
I cannot use the "init_signal_spy" procedure because this procedure doesn't give back a value into a string but just duplicates the behavior of a signal onto an other. As my project has to be as generic as possible, I work with variables declared into procedures and I cannot link a signal onto a variable.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're comfortable writing C code it should be straightforward to achieve what you want using the VHPI, although sadly despite being part of the VHDL standard Mentor are not planning to implement it. However it will also be possible using FLI although you're locked into a proprietary interface.

Something like this:

```
procedure get_signal_value_as_string(
    vhdl_path : IN string;
    vhdl_value: OUT string);

attribute FOREIGN of get_signal_value_as_string : procedure is “my_func mylib.so”;

procedure get_signal_value_as_string(
    vhdl_path : IN string;
    vhdl_value: OUT string) is
begin
    report “ERROR: foreign subprogram get_signal_value_as_string not called”;
end;
```

Then in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mti.h"


/* Convert a VHDL String array into a NULL terminated string */ 
static char *get_string(mtiVariableIdT id)
{
    static char buf[1000];
    mtiTypeIdT type;
    int len;
    mti_GetArrayVarValue(id, buf);
    type = mti_GetVarType(id);
    len = mti_TickLength(type);
    buf[len] = 0;
    return buf;
}


void my_func (
    mtiVariableIdT vhdl_path /* IN string */
    mtiVariableIdT vhdl_value /* OUT string */
    )
{
    mtiSignalIdT sigID = mti_FindSignal(get_string(vhdl_path));
    mtiInt32T value = mti_GetSignalValue(sigID);

    ...
}
```

Plenty of example code in the FLI manual.

Comment: Hi Chiggs, I didn't know FLI and it looks powerful. Do you know if it's possible to manage signal event in FLI ?

Comment: @grorel I think it is, although not as straightforward as in VHPI where you can just register a callback for a value change on a signal.  With FLI I believe you can create a process and sensitise it to the signal.

Comment: I've tryed FLI with some code similar to your example. I can compile it and call C functions from VHDL. But (there is always a but), the return value is always 0, and functions like mti_printmessage or mti_printformated don't write anything in transcript. Do you have any idea on how to solve that, or a link to a usefull website ? Thanks a lot

Comment: OK, I have recreated the whole C project and now everything works fine. I should have changed something wrong in project's parameters. Thank you Chiggs for your help

Answer (score 1):

**edited**

Sorry, I win the "did not read very carefully" award for the day...

Just for completeness, I'm leaving the part of my answer that deals with signal spy (which is a proprietary ModelSim method), even though you said it wouldn't work for you:

```
library modelsim_lib;
use modelsim_lib.util.all;

architecture ...
  signal local_sig ...
begin

  process
  begin
    init_signal_spy("/sim/path/to/signal/internal_sig", "local_sig");
```

With VHDL-2008 (if you have support for it), the standard way to access signals not in scope is hierarchical/external names, and as a bonus, it does both "write" and "read". I may be a bit rusty on the nuances, but you access them like:

```
<<signal .sim.path.to.signal.internal_sig : std_logic>>
```

And you should be able to use that in place of any normal in-scope identifier, I believe. Aliases, assignments, etc.

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your answer. I'm not sure that this solution could solve my problem as it uses the type "signal". My feelings is that what I'm trying to do is impossible in VHDL.

Comment: Ok, I think I misunderstood. You're reading a text file which specifies a signal name, and you're trying to access that signal name dynamically with a procedure of some sort?

Comment: exactly. for example, I can access a signal to write a new value like this :
signal_force("/tb/dut/path/to/signal" & signal_name, ..., signal_value);
with signal_name and signal_value defined as string.